# Print Java variable onto JSP page

Tags: java, jsp

I am having trouble with printing a java variable that I created in a java bean on a JSP page. I tried calling the get method from the java bean into the JSP but receiving syntax error and just using my current knowledge to figure it out.

```
public class StudentLoginBean {

@ManagedBean( name="studentLoginBean" )

public String username;

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}
```

This is what I tried.

```
<% String username = StudentLoginBean.getUsername("username"); %>
<div class="marginTable" data-pubid="<%=username%>" data-count="5"></div>
```

Comment: Use expression language ${username} / ${studentLoginBean.username}

Comment: use the jstl to resolve Bean property values with expression language as @kevcodez suggests. here is a link on how to use jsp tag libraries: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_standard_tag_library.htm

Comment: I've a question. Should @ManagedBean(name="studentLoginBean") be annotated over class, some thing like @ManagedBean(name="studentLoginBean")
public class StudentLoginBean {....}

Comment: `StudentLoginBean.getUsername("username");` You don't have a `get` method which takes a String parameter. Use a method you have actually defined.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly add the scope of the bean as ViewScoped, SessionScoped etc

```
@ViewScoped
```

@ManagedBean( name="studentLoginBean" )

Hope this will work. Thanks

Comment: also add @ViewScoped @ManagedBean( name="studentLoginBean" ) at top of the class.

Comment: Ok. I understand that I will have to add this on the Java Bean. But what do I do in the JSP page to call this?

Comment: @Tester The bean should be set in some scope. I see that you are trying to get the value of username in JSP, but where is the value set?

Comment: The value is set in a bean from a HTML page.

Answer (score 0):

I think the scope of the variable `username` is limited to the scriplet tag in which it is declared.

Declare the variable `username` globally using `<%!declaration here%>`.

Here's the updated code.

```
<%! String username; %>
<% username = StudentLoginBean.getUsername(); %>
<div class="marginTable" data-pubid="<%=username%>" data-count="5"></div>
```

Comment: I am getting an error. "required: no arguments. found: java.lang.String. reason: actual and formal arguments lists differ in length."

Comment: @ShrinivasShukla entire content of scriptlet (<% %>) tag goes into _jspService(req, resp) method. Also, all the html and plain text content goes into this method. So, that shouldn't be problem.

Comment: I am getting another error. "non-static method getUsername() cannot be referenced from a static context.

Comment: Thats not a big problem.
Change `public String getUsername()` to `public static String getUsername()`.